# Is this malloc wrapper safe?

Tags: memory, c++, integer-overflow

I am trying to stop integer overflow vulnerabilities by creating a simple wrapper around `malloc(3)` and related functions.  The idea is that it returns a `NULL` pointer if the amount of required memory is too large for the `size_t` argument (or zero).  However my implementation does not seem to be satisfying our static analyzer.  Can anyone identify what is wrong with this implementation?

```
template <typename T>
T* safe_malloc(const size_t num_elements)
{
  if (num_elements <= 0 || num_elements > SIZE_MAX / sizeof(T))
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  return static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T) * num_elements));
}
```

Usage:

```
// Previously:
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // single value
int *b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ATTACKER_CONTROLLED_VALUE); // array
if (b == NULL) {
  // out of memory
}


// Now:
int *a = safe_malloc<int>(1); // single value
int *b = safe_malloc<int>(ATTACKER_CONTROLLED_VALUE); // array
if (b == NULL) {
  // out of memory OR user provided value that would overflow, or zero
}
```

Comment: What static analyzer is it, and what does it say is wrong with the code?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Fortify, and it says that there is a possible integer overflow at the line where `malloc` is called.  The only other information it gives is the trace showing `ATTACKER_CONTROLLED_VALUE` is indeed attacker-controlled, which I already knew.

Comment: I think you are mixing C and C++, something that you need to reconsider, mixing the languages is not a good idea, not only for security reasons. Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new

Comment: @camp0 Trust me, if it were up to me all the C-isms would be ditched, but this is for a very large and old codebase that depends on them, but since the whole thing is compiled as C++, I figured I might as well take advantage of that where I could (hence the templates).

Comment: How can you have a negative `size_t`?

Comment: @multithr3at3d You can't.  Where do you see that?  I don't quite follow.

Comment: @matoro you're checking if it's `<= 0`

Comment: @multithr3at3d I am just trying to be extremely overcautious to get Fortify to recognize the code as safe.  It can't hurt to do `<= 0`, since the equality check against 0 is included in that.

Answer (score 1):

When you write,

```
template <typename T>T* safe_malloc(const size_t num_elements)
```

you're saying that `num_elements` can hold a full `size_t`. But if that is the case, then multiplying it by `sizeof(T)` might make it overflow, since the result also has to be `size_t`.

```
return static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T) * num_elements));
```

I do not know how to easily make fortify stop complaining. Possibly you can cast the desired memory amount to a larger size representation, check explicitly that it does not exceed `SIZE_MAX`, and if it does not, cast it back to `size_t`. That ought to be clear enough for the static analyzer to understand what's going on.

```
template <typename T> T* safe_malloc(const size_t num_elements) {
  unsigned long long required;
  required = num_elements;
  required *= sizeof(T);
  if ((0 == required) || (required > SIZE_MAX)) {
    return NULL;
  } else {
    return static_cast<T*>(malloc(required);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that not what the division check is doing?  It aborts if `num_elements > SIZE_MAX / sizeof(T)` which is the same as asserting that `num_elements * sizeof(T) <= SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: Yes. Your code works and has always worked. But I believe that the problem is that `fortify` doesn't understand what it does. I've added a different attempt (needn't check for negative numbers, as `size_t` is unsigned anyway)

Comment: I really appreciate the attempt, but unfortunately that still wasn't enough - it's still complaining about there being integer overflow at the `malloc` line.  I don't want to mark the answer as accepted just in case someone else with the same issue stumbles across it.

Comment: That's right. You are expected NOT to mark accepted an answer unless it REALLY helps you, otherwise there'd be no point. I tried casting `required` to `size_t`. It could be worthwhile to assign `required` to a `size_t` variable and use *that* variable in the malloc. I've tried looking for fortify examples (this kind of bound checking ought to be *common*!) but with no luck.